# How to get Color(JetpackCompose) from resources correctly?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-compose-textfield

I need to use resources in order to support different `BuildVars`, so I have `Color.kt` file where I define my colors, the problem is that if I get a color from the resources `colors.xml` like this

```
val MyWhiteColor: Color = Color(R.color.my_white_color)
```

and use it like this

```
    Text(
        text = ...,
        style = TextStyle(
            color = MyWhiteColor
        )
    )
```

I get blue color instead of white, however, if I change the implementation to

```
val MyWhiteColor: Color = Color(android.graphics.Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))
```

it works as expected and I get white color.

What am I missing? Why when I get the value from `colors.xml` the color converts to blue?

Comment: @BenTrengrove no it doesn't as I can use `colorResource` for @Composable functions only, however, in my `Color.kt` file I have defined my `MyWhiteColor` as a global val it is not a part of the @Composalbe function. The error I get in case if I try to go with your suggestion I get such an error `@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't load from an XML resource file outside of a Composable because Compose needs a context and it also has to react to configuration changes.

You can either just define your colors in Color.kt without XML color resources or you can load from a resource in a composable using:

`colorResource(R.color.my_white_color)`

Comment: it doesn't work as I can use `colorResource` for @Composable functions only, however, in my `Color.kt` file I have defined my `MyWhiteColor` as a global val it is not a part of the @Composalbe function. The error I get in case if I try to go with your suggestion I get such an error `@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function`

Comment: You will need it to be in a Composable context or else it might not react to configuration changes. If the color doesn't change based on configuration, there is no need to have it in a resource file in Compose.

Comment: This worked for me. I just needed to add `import com.mypackagename.R` manually.